# How to nest list inside list in Groovy

Tags: groovy, nested, iteration

Here is my original json

```
[
  {
    "city": "houston",
    "countyName": "county1",
    "email": "county1@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "city": "houston",
    "countyName": "county1",
    "email": "county1a@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "city": "houston",
    "countyName": "county2",
    "email": "county2@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "city": "dallas",
    "countyName": "county1",
    "email": "countyDallas1@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "city": "dallas",
    "countyName": "county2",
    "email": "countyDallas2@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

I want to convert into:

```
[
  {
    "city": "houston",
    "counties": [
      {
        "countyName": "county1",
        "email": [
          "county1@gmail.com",
          "county1a@gmail.com"
        ]
      },
      {
        "countyName": "county2",
        "email": [
          "county2@gmail.com"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "city": "dallas",
    "counties": [
      {
        "countyName": "county1",
        "email": [
          "county1@gmail.com"
        ]
      },
      {
        "countyName": "county2",
        "email": [
          "county2@gmail.com"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I did as below

```
groupBy{it.countyName}.values().collect{m-> [city: m.city[0], counties: m.counties.unique())]}
```

so far, I group by county name.
After that, I get the values.
Then I collect to new list.
I can get a unique list of counties but I have no idea how to nested as expected result

```
groupBy{it.countyName}.values().collect{m-> [city: m.city[0], counties: m.counties.unique())]}
```

Which command is used to nested the list of emails inside the list of counties

Answer (score 1):

You should start by grouping your input list by the city name. Then for each city, you can group remaining data by the county name to collect the list of email addresses. Consider the following example:

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def json = '''[
  {
    "city": "houston",
    "countyName": "county1",
    "email": "county1@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "city": "houston",
    "countyName": "county1",
    "email": "county1a@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "city": "houston",
    "countyName": "county2",
    "email": "county2@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "city": "dallas",
    "countyName": "county1",
    "email": "countyDallas1@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "city": "dallas",
    "countyName": "county2",
    "email": "countyDallas2@gmail.com"
  }
]'''

List list = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

def result = list.groupBy { it.city }.collect { cityName, cityData ->

    def counties = cityData.groupBy { it.countyName }.collect { countyName, countyData ->
        [countyName: countyName, email: countyData.collect { it.email }]
    }

    return [city: cityName, counties: counties]
}


println JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(result))
```

The output:

```
[
    {
        "city": "houston",
        "counties": [
            {
                "countyName": "county1",
                "email": [
                    "county1@gmail.com",
                    "county1a@gmail.com"
                ]
            },
            {
                "countyName": "county2",
                "email": [
                    "county2@gmail.com"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "city": "dallas",
        "counties": [
            {
                "countyName": "county1",
                "email": [
                    "countyDallas1@gmail.com"
                ]
            },
            {
                "countyName": "county2",
                "email": [
                    "countyDallas2@gmail.com"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```